# How to globally intercept outgoing http requests in nest.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am new in NestJs. In my case I need it to use it in role of Back-End for Front-End. Nest will get requests from UI and transfer it to some other Back-End. In order to do it I have to get incoming token from UI and send it further to real Back-End. I can get it and store via NestMiddleWare, but how do I send it? I mean I know I can manually assign it with each outgoing request via `httpService` but I wanna to do it once and globally. Can someone help?

Comment: read the doc https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters

Comment: Is this token going to be static or a dynamic one? Will it be sent with every request to your NestJS server? I can think of a few ways to possibly manage this

Comment: What do you mean static or dynamic? 

With each incoming request there will be a token which I need to send with appropriate outgoing request

Comment: Static: it is the same token with each request. Dynamic: the token changes (or can change) with each request.

Comment: It is dynamic since it has expiration time, after which the UI requests the new one and from now send this new one

Comment: @MordechaiDror Did you have any luck finding a solution for this?

Comment: @zwebie I can't write here the code since I left work when I got this issue, but the point is to work on Axios since it is the library NestJS works with

Comment: @MordechaiDror Where do you store the token in the middleware and how do you access it in axios?

Comment: @zwebie I stored it in dedicated service and accessed it via dependency injection, but since it was not secure, the token was stored outside of request scope. E.g. for example user1 sent request, server received it, stored the token, but before it went to api gateway user2 also sent request, so his token is stored in the store, after that server proceeded with user1 request, but the problem is that now it will use user2 token for it... so in the end we decided manually transfer token from ui request context to api gateway request context, so the token is always lie only in its request context